# How i can do group by on all my messages

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am trying to get the number of all messages per user

```
msg 1 = SenderId =1  , ReciverId =2 
msg 2 = SenderId =2  , ReciverId =1
msg 3 = SenderId =1  , ReciverId =2
```

> i consider 1 chat with the same user as one message so in my example
>   the query need to reurn that i have one message

what is the query for that?
 i wrote a query at bottom that tell what i want
but is ilegal, how i write working one?

```
public class UserMessages
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long SenderId { get; set; }
    public long ReciverId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTime { get; set; }
    public bool FastMessage { get; set; }
    public bool SenderDelete { get; set; }
    public bool ReciverDelete { get; set; }
    public bool ReciverRead { get; set; }
}

        var UserMessages = db.UserMessages
                             .Where(x => (x.SenderId == id && x.SenderDelete == false) ||
                                         (x.ReciverId == x.Id && x.ReciverDelete == false))
                             .GroupBy(x => new { x.ReciverId, x.SenderId })
                             .GroupBy((y, w) => y.Key.SenderId == w.Key.ReciverId
                                                && y.Key.ReciverId == w.Key.SenderId)
                             .Count();
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to get in the end?

Answer (score 0):

My take would be something like this:

```
var result = db.UserMessages
               .Where(x => x.SenderId == id || x.ReceiverId == id)
               .Select(x => x.ReceiverId == id ? x.SenderId : x.ReceiverId)
               .Distinct()
               .Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = 1; // the ID of the person to count chat partners for

var chatPartnerCount = db.UserMessages
    .Where(x => x.SenderId == id && !x.SenderDelete || x.ReceiverId == id && !x.ReceiverDelete)
    .GroupBy(x => x.SenderId == id ? x.ReceiverId : x.SenderId) // group by the chat partner
    .Count(); // count the number of unique chat partners
```